# pivot table for new and old customer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

```
  customer  purchase_id    payment_status   price currency  payment_date    
1   Andy        6         REPAID             100    GBP   2020-04-16 
2   Randy      10       IN_PROGRESS          10000  SEK   2020-04-17
```

I would like to make a pivot, where I can see how many old and new customers come to purchase.
Expected output:

```
       new_customers    old_customers
Jan          1                3
Feb          5                2
```

I am stuck after:

```
df['year']=df['payment_date'].dt.year
df['month']=df['payment_date'].dt.month
df2=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("customer", sort=False)["purchase_id"].count())
df2=number_of_purchase.reset_index()
df2.columns = ['merchant_code','number_of_purchase']
df2['repeat_customer']=np.where(df['number_of_purchase']>1,'old_customers','new_customers')
```

I don't know how to integrate `df2` with `df`, where in `df`, a customer can appear more than once, with different purchase_id, price and payment dates..
The final part of the code probably looks like this:

```
df.groupby(["year","month", "repeat_customers"])["repeat_customers"].count()
```

but please feel free to change my code, the output is more important.

Answer (score 0):

- your sample data does not have enough features,  so I have generated a random dataset that matches the structure
- it's far simpler to work with month starts,  so just move to these
- a definition is needed for new customer,  I've implied from your code it's definition
- straight forward to calculate with this definition
- finally reshape results to structure you want
- you may want to format the month,  in output DF

```
import numpy as np
d = pd.date_range("01-Jan-2020", periods=10, freq="W")
c = ['tenetur', 'quae', 'rem', 'maxime', 'sunt']
df = pd.DataFrame({"customer":np.random.choice(c, len(d)),
             "purchase_id":np.random.randint(1,10, len(d)),
             "payment_status":np.random.choice(["REPAID","IN_PROGRESS"],len(d)),
             "price":np.random.randint(100,10000, len(d)),
             "currency":np.random.choice(["GBP","SEK"],len(d)),
             "payment_date":d})

# only interested with month start
df2 = (df.assign(ms=df.payment_date - pd.to_timedelta(df.payment_date.dt.day-1, "d"),
           # find first time a customer made a purchase
          fms=lambda dfa: dfa.groupby("customer")["ms"].transform("first"),
           # if month of purchase and first month customer made a purchase are same, new ...
          new_customer=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.ms==dfa.fms, "new_customers", "old_customers")
         )
 # with the prep it's a simple count
 .groupby(["ms","new_customer"])["customer"].count()
 # format the results
 .to_frame().unstack(1).fillna(0).droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

#### df

|  | customer | purchase_id | payment_status | price | currency | payment_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sunt | 5 | REPAID | 9228 | SEK | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 1 | tenetur | 6 | IN_PROGRESS | 1458 | SEK | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 |
| 2 | maxime | 7 | IN_PROGRESS | 9798 | GBP | 2020-01-19 00:00:00 |
| 3 | sunt | 1 | IN_PROGRESS | 2418 | SEK | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |
| 4 | maxime | 8 | IN_PROGRESS | 6608 | GBP | 2020-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 5 | sunt | 4 | IN_PROGRESS | 2341 | GBP | 2020-02-09 00:00:00 |
| 6 | rem | 7 | REPAID | 8961 | GBP | 2020-02-16 00:00:00 |
| 7 | quae | 2 | REPAID | 7068 | GBP | 2020-02-23 00:00:00 |
| 8 | maxime | 1 | IN_PROGRESS | 4872 | SEK | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 9 | tenetur | 1 | REPAID | 2860 | GBP | 2020-03-08 00:00:00 |

#### df2

| ms | new_customers | old_customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 0 | 2 |